# Cambiar nombre a un atributo de otra clase en java

Tags: java, poo

```
package Problema;

public class ModeloEstudiante {

private int id;
private String nombre;
private int evaluacion;
private double notaFisica;
private double notaMatematicas;
private double notaQuimica;

public ModeloEstudiante(int id, String nombre, int evaluacion, double notaFisica, double notaMatematicas, double notaQuimica) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.evaluacion = evaluacion;
    this.notaFisica = notaFisica;
    this.notaMatematicas = notaMatematicas;
    this.notaQuimica = notaQuimica;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getEvaluacion() {
    return evaluacion;
}

public void setEvaluacion(int evaluacion) {
    this.evaluacion = evaluacion;
}

public double getNotaFisica() {
    return notaFisica;
}

public void setNotaFisica(double notaFisica) {
    this.notaFisica = notaFisica;
}

public double getNotaMatematicas() {
    return notaMatematicas;
}

public void setNotaMatematicas(double notaMatematicas) {
    this.notaMatematicas = notaMatematicas;
}

public double getNotaQuimica() {
    return notaQuimica;
}

public void setNotaQuimica(double notaQuimica) {
    this.notaQuimica = notaQuimica;
}
}

class Estudiantes {

ModeloEstudiante dato;
ModeloEstudiante dato2;
ModeloEstudiante dato3;

public Estudiantes() {
    dato = new ModeloEstudiante(1, "Camilo", 1, 5.0, 4.2, 3.5);
    dato2 = new ModeloEstudiante(1, "Camilo", 2, 3.0, 2.2, 2.5);
    dato3 = new ModeloEstudiante(1, "Camilo", 3, 4.0, 1.0, 5.0);
}

public String getDato1() {
    return "ID N°: " + dato.getId()
            + "\nNombre: " + dato.getNombre()
            + "\nParcial N°: " + dato.getEvaluacion()
            + "\nNota Fisica: " + dato.getNotaFisica()
            + "\nNota Matematicas: " + dato.getNotaMatematicas()
            + "\nNota Quimica: " + dato.getNotaQuimica();
}

public String getDato2() {
    return "ID N°: " + dato2.getId()
            + "\nNombre: " + dato2.getNombre()
            + "\nParcial N°: " + dato2.getEvaluacion()
            + "\nNota Fisica: " + dato2.getNotaFisica()
            + "\nNota Matematicas: " + dato2.getNotaMatematicas()
            + "\nNota Quimica: " + dato2.getNotaQuimica();
}

public String getDato3() {
    return "ID N°: " + dato3.getId()
            + "\nNombre: " + dato3.getNombre()
            + "\nParcial N°: " + dato3.getEvaluacion()
            + "\nNota Fisica: " + dato3.getNotaFisica()
            + "\nNota Matematicas: " + dato3.getNotaMatematicas()
            + "\nNota Quimica: " + dato3.getNotaQuimica();
}

public double notasPrimerEval() {
    return dato.getNotaFisica() + dato.getNotaMatematicas() + dato.getNotaQuimica();
}

public double notasSegundaEval() {
    return dato2.getNotaFisica() + dato2.getNotaMatematicas() + dato2.getNotaQuimica();
}

public double notasTercerEval() {
    return dato3.getNotaFisica() + dato3.getNotaMatematicas() + dato3.getNotaQuimica();
}

public double notasFinalFisica() {
    return (dato.getNotaFisica() + dato2.getNotaFisica() + dato3.getNotaFisica())/3;
}

}

class Interfaz {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Estudiantes estudiantes = new Estudiantes();

    System.out.println(estudiantes.getDato1());
    System.out.println(estudiantes.getDato2());
    System.out.println(estudiantes.getDato3());


    System.out.println("Nota Final de fisica "+estudiantes.notasFinalFisica());
}
}
```

Mi pregunta es como cambiar desde la clase Interfaz el nombre o id de un estudiante.
que debo implementar en la clase Estudiantes para poder hacerlo?.
Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de cada objeto estudiantes declarado en tu clase Interfaz defines 3 objetos de tipo ModeloEstudiante que es donde le puedes modificar el nombre, id o lo que haga falta.

Para acceder a ellos lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
Estudiantes estudiantes = new Estudiantes();

System.out.println(estudiantes.getDato1()); //Esto pinta los datos del estudiante (1, "Camilo", 1, 5.0, 4.2, 3.5)

//Dentro de estudiantes accedemos al primero de ellos y cambiamos sus propiedades
estudiantes.dato.setNombre("Paco");  //Le cambiamos el nombre
estudiantes.dato.setId(2);           //Le cambiamos el id
```

Esto se puede hacer si el atributo dato es público, sino tendrías que, o declararlo público o hacer un método get para poder acceder a él.

Comment: Dale Gracias...